# Get Selected value from Golang Gorm Query

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, go-gin

I want to get user data after I do query using gorm

```
item := []models.User{}

if config.DB.First(&item, "email = ?", email).RecordNotFound() || len(item) == 0 {
    c.JSON(500, gin.H{
        "status":  "error",
        "message": "record not found"})
    c.Abort()
    return
}

c.JSON(200, gin.H{
    "status": "success",
    "data":   item,
})
```

And here are my models

```
type User struct {
gorm.Model
Stores     []Store // to show that customer can have many stores
UserName   string
FullName   string
Email      string `gorm:"unique_index"`
Password   string
SocialID   string
Provider   string
Avatar     string
Role       bool `gorm:"default:0"`
HaveStore  bool `gorm:"default:0"`
isActivate bool `gorm:"default:0"`
}
```

I just want to get the UserName after do query from gorm, how to get that? I'm using `item.Username`but, the error show that `item.UserName undefined (type []models.User has no field or method UserName)`

Comment: You should change response code from 500 to 404 for 'record not found' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` denotes a [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), which means that `item` is not a single user but a slice of users, and slices don't have fields, they have elements which are the individual instances stored in them, to access these elements you use an [index expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) (`s[i]`). Either do `item[0].UserName` or declare `item` as a single user, not a slice. i.e. `item := model.User{}` then you can use the [selector expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors) `item.UserName`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get `UserName` from slice of user that the problem.
If email is a unique field database then you can use the user model only rather using slice of user.

```
item := models.User{}
config.DB.First(&item, "email = ?", email)
```

Then you can access like username like `item.UserName`

Comment: yes, i just realize that, i'm using a slice, while i just need a row. thank you